# Why won't one of the String constants format in the toString method?

Tags: java

Every other variable will format accordingly but the BANK_NAME constants will just not adhere to any of the formatting. Any reason why? Solutions?

```
 /**
 * Returns information about the CD account
 * @return  formatted string for CD account information
 */
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("Investment Type: %.13s\n" +
                         "Held By: %.34s\n" + //THIS ONE WILL NOT FORMAT
                         "%30s\n" +
                         "Balance: %15.2f\n" +
                         "Annual Int. Rate: $%4.2f\n",
                         ACCOUNT_TYPE,BANK_NAME,BANK_ADDRESS,getBalance(),calcInterest());
}
```

OUTPUT SAMPLE:

```
       Investment Type:  CD 1 Yr
       Held By: First Rochester Bank
                         Rochester, NY
       Balance:          5000.00
       Annual Int. Rate: $177.83
```

Comment: What's the declaration of `BANK_ADDRESS`? What do you mean "will just adhere to any of the formatting"? Can you provide some sample output showing the problem?

Comment: I meant "NOT adhere.." I added sample output.

Comment: Please explain what's wrong with the output. It looks like I would expect from the format.

Comment: "First Rochester Bank" should also move over to the right...

Comment: The point is used to specify decimal width. Try removing the point from %.34s and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: Plus BANK_ACCOUNT may have a previous format, messing with your new format.

Comment: @Alex For strings and other general conversions, the *precision* (what goes after dot) is the **maximum width** of the formatted value; the value is right-truncated if necessary (see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html and the related [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax))

Comment: Ok. He should change the width and not the precision, as we don't care about maximum width: Width. The minimum width of the formatted value; the value is padded if necessary. By default the value is left-padded with blanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the data to align on the left of a specific column in the output, you should do it with explicit padding rather than with field widths. For one thing, if you get the alignment correct using your method for one name, it will be wrong for another name of different length. Try this instead:

```
public String toString()
{
    return String.format("Investment Type:  %.13s%n" +
                         "Held By:          %s%n" +
                         "                  %s%n" +
                         "Balance:          %.2f%n" +
                         "Annual Int. Rate: $%4.2f%n",
                         ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                         BANK_NAME,
                         BANK_ADDRESS,
                         getBalance(),
                         calcInterest()
    );
}
```

Note that I changed the newline escape sequences with a newline format specifier. It's generally better to do that for cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Thank you so much. This absolutely worked, apparently you saw something was wrong. Can you clarify a little more why I needed to use this instead?

Comment: @user2840682 - The format you were using for `BANK_NAME` (unlike for `BANK_ADDRESS`) specified a precision, not a field width. The precision for string conversions is used as a maximum width, but does not result in any padding. It also was clear that the width used for `BANK_ADDRESS` was not going to give the desired result for an address that had a different number of characters than "Rochester, NY". Once it was clear that you wanted everything lined up in a column, the solution was obvious: put the required spaces in the format itself and left-justify all fields (by eliminating widths).